# cannot install ros-electric-desktop-full right now

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot install ros-electric-desktop-full at the moment. I am not sure that whether the repo now invalid or some thing wrong with me. The result I got are many unmet dependencies, but when I go to the repo by the web browser they still be there! Can anyone tell me what am I supposed to do please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11637/cannot-install-ros-electric-desktop-full-right-now/) by [JrManit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1259/jrmanit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-22**:
Please provide more information about what architecture and OS you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What OS and repo are you using? Please quote your sources.lists and show the console output of your problems.  If you don't provide more information we can't help you, please see the support guidelines at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Based on your outputs it looks like you're using lucid.
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages shows consistent versions of opencv.  As does http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-15**:
Excuse me, but may I ask when could the problem mentioned in http://answers.ros.org/question/2887/libopencv23-dev-conflict be resolved, please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have also had this problem with Lucid i386.

There seems to be a version mismatch in the libopencv2.3 package.  The version currently in the repo is 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-4~lucid while most of the ros-electic packages depend on the exact libopencv=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~lucid version, which has now been removed from the repo.

The fix probably needs to happen on the repo maintainer end and should be one of:

- Update ros-electric dependencies on all packages to libopencv=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-4~lucid
- Update ros-electric dependencies on all packages to a more permissive version range so that this type of error won't happen when the minor package revision is incremented.

---

Originally posted by [ntd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1264/ntd/) with karma: 36 on 2011-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed lately that aptitude gives a lot of dependency problems and conflicts for ROS related packages, while apt-get is able to install everything just fine. So make sure you use apt-get and not aptitude.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-03**:
My conflict concerns opencv2.3 and the Ubuntu-installed libcv (which other programs depend on): http://answers.ros.org/question/2657/solve-conflict-between-ubuntu-libcv21-and-ros

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-11-03**:
Yes. This is on my home laptop, I can't test it right now. what exactly are your conflicts using apt-get? I should note that i'm using oneiric and ROS electric.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-03**:
Does this completely update for you, and not hold back a few packages with conflicts?